# Cocoa tableview checkbox state lost on scroll

Tags: swift, cocoa, checkbox, tableview, state

I have a viewbase tableview with checkboxes. I create custom class for nstableviewcell to manipulate the checkbox for every rows.

The problem is when I checked mutiple checkboxes in tableview and scroll down. Then I scroll back, the checkbox state disappeared although the selected data was in the array.

Here is my tableview

```
else if tableView.tag == 2{
        if (tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "AlbumColumn" .   {
            if let cell: MyCustomViewCell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "AlbumColumn"), owner: self) as? MyCustomViewCell
            {
                cell.AlbumCbx.state = NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 0)
                cell.AlbumCbx.title = albums[row]!
                cell.onClickAlbumCbx = { sender in
                    if !selected_album.isEmpty{
                        if cell.AlbumCbx.state.rawValue == 1{
                            selected_album.append(albums[row]!)

                        } else {
                            selected_album = selected_album.filter({ $0 != albums[row]! })
                        }
                    }
                }

                return cell
            }
        }
    }
```

I have search on google and stackoverflow and I find out the way to solve this is method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row:Int) -> NSTableRowView? {

}
```

Although I don't know to implement this method.

Comment: Is your `selected_album` variable a value type object like a struct? Or is it a reference type? If it's a value type and you're creating a variable to update something like `let selected_album = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]` then your variable is a copy of the item in the datasource array and you're modifying the copy, not the item in the datasource. Then when you scroll and the cell reloads you're populating the cell with the original, and not your updated variable. You'll need to either use a reference type or update your datasource array with your updated `selected_album` item.

Comment: Invisible table cell views are reused. In `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` you set the title but you set the state to 0. Set the state to the correct state.

Comment: @Willeke , Strange, I delete this "cell.AlbumCbx.state = NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 0)" and it did show some check marks after scrolling although the table move the check mark of checkbox1 to other checkbox.

Comment: thanks guy, I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote like this and it worked like a charm

```
cell.AlbumCbx.state = NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 0)

    for s in selected_album{
        if cell.AlbumCbx.title == s
        {
           //print(true, cell.AlbumCbx.title)
           cell.AlbumCbx.state = NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 1)    
        }
    }
```